# Rake tasks won't run inside of my sinatra app

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, sinatra, rake, require

I have a sinatra app with a Rakefile.rake and server.rb file. In the server.rb file I have

```
get '/' do
    rake :test
end
```

the app loads up but crashes when I load localhost:4567/ and says undefined method 'rake' for sinatra application. I try and require the file by using

```
require '/home/user/project/Rakefile'
```

and I also try Rakefile.rake but both give me an error that reads "require cannot load such file." I'm using Ubuntu.

I'm not sure why sinatra can't load the rakefile, but when I run rake test in terminal that works.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get '/' do
    system 'rake test'
end
```

Comment: 'rake :test' does not work but 'rake test' does work. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @mgtemp Because you invoke rake from the command line with a word as an argument, not with a Ruby symbol.

Comment: What if I want to run rake :test outside of the get? Or before any of the gets? rake :test can't be found. Will I always have to use system 'rake test'? How come other .rb files in the same project can use rake :test but the sinatra one cant?

Comment: @mgtemp `rake` in your example is a method call. If your Sinatra app does not have that method loaded then how can it call it?

Comment: @mgtemp You're asking questions outside the scope of your original question. If you want to `require 'rake'` and invoke rake methods inside an application, then you certainly can; but while that's related, it's a very different question. See if the question has already been answered elsewhere. If not, ask it, and use your "other rb files" from the project to show why that's not working for you.