# running rake task with rufus-scheduler and sinatra -- it only runs one time instead of the desired interval

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rake, rufus-scheduler

i have a rakefile in the same folder as my app.rb file, I can successfully call the rakefile task once, but it doesnt run the task more than once. It should run every 3 seconds.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rufus/scheduler'
require 'rake'

class MySchedule < Sinatra::Base
  scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
  rake = Rake::Application.new
  Rake.application = rake
  rake.init
  rake.load_rakefile

  scheduler.every '3s' do
    rake[:first_test].invoke
  end
end

MySchedule.new
```

Answer (score 0):

solved, was able to successfully call using `system 'rake first_test'`

source: [Rake tasks won't run inside of my sinatra app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098691/rake-tasks-wont-run-inside-of-my-sinatra-app)